# stat not recognizing directoies

Tags: c, file, stat

Hello I´m working on a du implementation that only calculates the size of regular files, so far I got this :

```
 childAnswer* list(char* path){
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *filei;
    struct stat stats;
    directory = opendir(path);
    int size = 0;
    dQhead* q = createDQ();
    if (directory != NULL)  
    {
        while ((filei=readdir(directory))!=NULL){
            stat(filei->d_name, &stats);  
            //printf("SIZE : %d\n",  size);
            char *buf = malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(filei->d_name)+2);
            strcpy(buf,path);
            strcat(buf,"/");
            strcat(buf,filei->d_name);
            if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode)) {
                stat(buf, &stats);
                if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode)) {
                    if (strcmp(filei->d_name,".")!=0 && (strcmp(filei->d_name,"..")!=0)) {
                        addToQ(q,createD(buf));
                        printf(" Directory : %s\n",buf);

                    }
                }  
            }
            else{
                printf(" Non directory : %s\n",buf);
                size = size + stats.st_blocks;
            }

            free(buf);
        }
        printf(" path : %s\n",  path);
        printf("Return :\n");
        printQ(q);
        printf("Finish returning \n");
        childAnswer* answer = createCA(path, size, q);

        closedir(directory);
        return answer;
    }
    else {
        perror(NULL);    
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The problem is that it does not recognize some directories files and therefore it won't go as deep, I mean, if id does not recognize a directory it would not use the `addToQ()` function that would add to a queue of directories for the `list` function to work on the next iteration.
The reason I coded it this way is because I have to implement this using threads, so a every thread would run this function with a different directory .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to do the `stat` on the full pathname. The code *does* do a `stat` on the full path, but only after it does a `stat` on the partial path.  The `stat` on the partial path needs to be removed.

Comment: @user3386109: Alternatively, do the sane thing and `fstatat()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just changed that, but I still have the same issue, maybe it's  because I was doing `stat` once again later with the full path here: `stat(buf, &stats);`. Edit: Never mind, it works now, thank you both.

Comment: Could avoid a lot of `malloc()` calls with one before the while loop when field `d_name` is an array : `malloc(strlen(path)+ sizeof(filei->d_name)+2);`